# I need to Send email from ipage host using PHPMailer

Tags: phpmailer, sendmail

I can not send an email through ipage host using the PHPMailer.

I have the following Error:

> ** Mail error: The following From address failed: maria@mydomain.com : Called Mail() without being connected

```
<?php
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
require 'PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';

function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body, $is_gmail = false) { 
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 

    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
    $mail->Host = 'mail.mydomain.com';
    $mail->Port = 993;  
    $mail->Username = "maria@cgi.mydomain.com";  
    $mail->Password = "mypassword";   


    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Message sent!';
        return true;
    }
}


$msg = 'Hello World';
$subj = 'test mail message';
$to = 'mail@gmail.com';
$from = 'maria@mydomain.com';
$name = 'maa';


    if (!smtpmailer($to, $from, $name, $subj, $msg, false)) {
        if (!empty($error)) echo $error;
    } else {
        echo 'Yep, the message is send (after doing some hard work)';
    }
?>
```

---

Error log moved here:

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 ESMTP Wed, 20 Sep 2017 09:57:47 -0400: UCE strictly prohibited SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-bosauthsmtp15.yourhostingaccount.com Hello localhost [156.204.159.206] 250-SIZE 34603008 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250-STARTTLS 250 HELP SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 TLS go ahead SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-bosauthsmtp15.yourhostingaccount.com Hello localhost [156.204.159.206] 250-SIZE 34603008 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250 HELP SMTP -> ERROR: Username not accepted from server: 535 Incorrect authentication data SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Reset OK SMTP -> FROM SERVER:550 bosauthsmtp15: Host 156.204.159.206: No unauthenticated relaying permitted SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from server: 550 bosauthsmtp15: Host 156.204.159.206: No unauthenticated relaying permitted The following From address failed: maria@cgi.mydomain.com : MAIL not accepted from server,550,bosauthsmtp15: Host 156.204.159.206: No unauthenticated relaying permitted

SMTP server error: bosauthsmtp15: Host 156.204.159.206: No unauthenticated these is what I get

relaying permitted Mail error: The following From address failed: maria@cgi.mydomain.com : MAIL not accepted from server,550,bosauthsmtp15: Host 156.204.159.206: No unauthenticated relaying permitted

SMTP server error: bosauthsmtp15: Host 156.204.159.206: No unauthenticated relaying permitted

SMTP server error: bosauthsmtp15: Host 156.204.159.206: No unauthenticated relaying permitted
```

Comment: You're using SMTP but connecting to an IMAP port number, so all SMTP commands are likely to fail. Try connecting to port 587 (with `SMTPSecure = 'tls'`).

Comment: I tried what u suggested and I got the following error   

Mail error: The following From address failed: maria@mydomain.com : MAIL not accepted from server,550,bosauthsmtp15: Host 156.204.159.206: No unauthenticated relaying permitted

SMTP server error: bosauthsmtp15: Host 156.204.159.206: No unauthenticated relaying permitted

SMTP server error: bosauthsmtp15: Host 156.204.159.206: No unauthenticated relaying permitted

Comment: This suggests that your authentication failed. I can't tell any more without seeing the full transcript. Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` to see it.

Comment: please view the error :)

Comment: That's not a full log and you're using an ancient, buggy, and vulnerable version of PHPMailer - [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).